# Discord bot disconnecting and going offline after a certain time

Tags: python-3.x, django-models, pycord

My bot stays online for around 10 to 15 minutes, after that it goes offline and randomly comes back online and crashes after a few moments

## bot.py

```
import os
import asyncio
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
from decouple import config
from django.core import management
from manage import init_django
import json

init_django()
management.call_command('makemigrations')
management.call_command('migrate')

# with open('data.json', 'r', encoding='utf-8') as data_file:
#   data = json.load(data_file)
#   management.call_command('loaddata', 'data.json')

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix='-', intents=discord.Intents.all(),
                      application_id=...)


@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('I am ready')

@client.event
async def on_disconnect():
    print('Disconnected') # I always get this message

async def load():
    for filename in os.listdir('./cogs'):
        if filename.endswith('.py'):
            client.load_extension(f'cogs.{filename[:-3]}')


async def main():
    await load()
    await client.start(config("TOKEN"))

asyncio.run(main())
```

## breedings.py

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
from db.models import Monster
from channels.db import database_sync_to_async
from django.db.models import Q


@database_sync_to_async
def get_monster_breedings(name, rarety):
    monster = Monster.objects.filter(
        Q(name_translations__portuguese_name__icontains=name) |
        Q(name_translations__english_name__icontains=name), rarety__name=rarety
    ).prefetch_related('name_translations', 'rarety').first()

    if monster:
        prefetch_list = ['monster_1', 'monster_2', 'monster_3', 'island']
        prefetch_list += ['monster_1__name_translations',
                          'monster_2__name_translations',
                          'monster_3__name_translations']
        return list(monster.breedings.all().prefetch_related(*prefetch_list))
    return []


class Breedings(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, client):
        self.client = client

    @commands.slash_command(name='ping', description='ping')
    async def ping(self, ctx: discord.ApplicationContext):
        await ctx.respond('pong')

    @commands.slash_command(name='breeding')
    @discord.option(name='rarety', choices=['Common', 'Rare', 'Epic'])
    async def breeding(self,
                       ctx,
                       monster: str,
                       rarety: str):
        breedings = await get_monster_breedings(name=monster, rarety=rarety)
        if not breedings:
            return await ctx.respond('Nada encontrado ;-;')

        monster_obj = breedings[0].monster
        embed = discord.Embed(url=str(monster_obj.url), title=monster_obj.name)
        embed.set_thumbnail(
            url=monster_obj.image_url,)

        default_times, enhancend_times = set(), set()
        for breed in breedings:
            m1, m2, m3 = breed.monster_1, breed.monster_2, breed.monster_3
            if breed.monster_3:
                value = f'Any({m1}, {m2}, {m3})'
            elif m2 is None:
                value = f'{m1} + Three elements'
            else:
                value = f'{m1} + {m2}'

            embed.add_field(name=breed.island or 'any island',
                            value=value, inline=False)
            default_times.add(breed.default_time)
            enhancend_times.add(breed.enhanced_time)

        embed.set_footer(
            text=f'Tempo padrão: {"; ".join(map(str, default_times))}\n'
                 f'Melhorado: {"; ".join(map(str, enhancend_times))}')

        await ctx.respond(embed=embed)


def setup(client):
    client.add_cog(Breedings(client))
```

I've been looking for something related for a few days and the closest thing I found was that it could be a problem with the discord api, but no way to solve it

When I manage to capture an error message it is something like: `discord.errors.NotFound: 404 Not Found (error code: 10062): Unknown interaction`

Comment: There is a lot of thing going on in your code (Django, Discord). Can you reduce your code to isolate what trigger your error code? Have a look at how to create a [example]

Comment: Have you tried `discord.Bot()` instead of `commands.Bot()` with `client.run()`?

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of things that don't make sense.

1. You added `load()` as asynchronous in the event loop before the bot has even started
2. You use `client.start()` in an asynchronous function but you never add it to the loop. If you were to add it to the loop, it would look like:

```py
try:
    loop.run_until_complete(start(*args, **kwargs))
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    loop.run_until_complete(close())
    # cancel all tasks lingering
finally:
    loop.close()
```

The above is the equivalent to `bot.run()` and is found in the [Pycord documentation](https://docs.pycord.dev/en/stable/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.Bot.run).

If you don't know what you're doing in regards to `client.start()`, it's best to just use `client.run()` instead.

(I'm using client and bot interchangeably, but the class should be [`discord.ext.commands.Bot()`](https://docs.pycord.dev/en/stable/ext/commands/api.html#bot))